# need help solving coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need opinions on how to solve these equations. I looked into Laplace-transform but have not tried anything yet. I want help before proceeding.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot x^2$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=-10-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot y^2$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the last squares in each equation? Without them it is the velocity dynamics for a ballistic motion in air. // Laplace only works for linear DE.

Comment: What exactly is the task? Do you have initial or boundary values to find some distinct solution or is the task some general "find as much information as possible"?

Comment: I want to try to get an equation for x and y, whether thats possible or not. These equations came from the quadratic drag acting on a projectile. -cv^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag or friction in air is indeed of size $cv^2$, but its direction is $-\hat v$ where $\hat v=\frac{\vec v}{v}$, so that in total the vector force is $-cv\vec v$ (using $v=\|\vec v\|$). This gives the component equations
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot x
\\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=-10-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot y
\end{align}
There is indeed a first integral to be found, it has a whole wunderkind story attached (more a re-discovery of a decades old observation), but as this first integral also only gives an implicit non-linear equation between $x$ and $y$ its practical usefulness is in doubt. Use numerical methods.